# setting NetworkStream.ReceiveTimeout not triggering exception

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, stream

This is a continuation of the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542235/read-specific-number-of-bytes-from-networkstream) question. I am new to network programming, so I am just writing small sample stuff to gain understanding, but somewhat struggling with explaining results.

It seems setting `NetworkStream.ReceiveTimeout` is not working correctly when client that was supposed to be sending data simply closes before sending all the expected data.

Here is the sample code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10001);
    listener.Start();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WriterThread);

    using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        client.ReceiveTimeout = (int)new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2).TotalMilliseconds;
        stream.ReadTimeout = (int)new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2).TotalMilliseconds;
        ReceiveMessage(stream, 1024);
    }

    listener.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}


private static void WriterThread(object state)
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 10001));
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("obviously less than 1024 bytes");
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(10000); // comment out 
        }
    }
}


private static byte[] ReceiveMessage(Stream stream, int length)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    int bufferFill = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        bufferFill += stream.Read(buffer, bufferFill, buffer.Length - bufferFill);
        if (buffer.Length == bufferFill)
            return buffer;

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

This version works correctly triggering exception on the `stream.Read()` call. However If I comment out `Thread.Sleep(10000)`, the client closes connection, but listener fails to recognize it. Main thread gets stuck inside the `while(true)` loop. The `stream.Read()` keeps returning zero, but no exception thrown.

Is this normal? If so how am I expected to handle abnormal client disconnections?

Comment: When `Stream.Read()` returns zero, it indicates that you have reached the ned of the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this sounds normal. There is no receive- or read timeout because the client has disconnected. This means that no more data is available for reading and the stream will return 0 immediately just as documented.

I would modify your ReceiveMessage method to something like the following:

```
private static byte[] ReceiveMessage(Stream stream, int length)
{
   byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
   int bufferFill = 0;

   while (true)
   {
      int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, bufferFill, buffer.Length - bufferFill);
      if (bytesRead == 0)
         throw new Exception("No more data available.");
      bufferFill += bytesRead;
      if (buffer.Length == bufferFill)
         return buffer;

      Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
```

Clearly if the stream.Read() call returns 0 before we have received all the expected bytes there must have been some form of disconnection or similar. Either way we will never get any more data from the stream.

**Edit:** The Stream class has no notion of a "message". The Read method blocks until more data becomes available if none is already in the buffer. It will however return 0 when no more data can be received, which in this case means the connection is closed.

Comment: is that still true if connection is used to send multiple messages with intervals of inactivity?

Comment: Yes. The Stream class has no notion of a "message". The Read method blocks until more data becomes available if none is already in the buffer. It will however return 0 when no more data can be received, which in this case means the connection is closed.

Comment: +1, great explanation. I usually edit my answers to add updated information and just post a "read my update" commment. It makes it easier to find all information for future readers.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Thread.Sleep(100)`? Wouldn't the code be more efficient without it?